# How to re-direct to state based on flag using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have `userAccess` flag in controller if it returns false i want hide all the application from user and redirect user to `access.html` with some access required form So with below code it throws error `transition superseded`, Any idea how to achieve this task with angularjs `ui.router` ?

mainCtrl.js

```
$scope.cookie = $cookies.get(jklHr');
var parts = $scope.cookie.split("|");
var uidParts = parts[7].split(",");
$scope.newUser._id = uidParts[0];
var userAccess = AuthService.getCurrentUser($scope.newUser._id);

    if(!userAccess) {
        console.log("Access Deinied");
        $state.go('app.access');
    }
```

app.js

```
angular.module('App', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.bootstrap.pagination',
    'ngSanitize',
    'timer',
    'toastr',
    'ngCookies',
]).config(function($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'use strict'

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
        var $state = $injector.get('$state');
        $state.go('app.home');
    });

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'web/global/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'view/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.dit', {
            url: '/dit',
            templateUrl: 'view/partials/logs.html',
            controller: 'LogsCtrl',
            resolve: {
                changeStateData: function(LogsFactory) {
                    var env = 'dit';
                    return LogsFactory.resolveData(env)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            return response.data
                        });
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.access', {
            url: '/access',
            templateUrl: 'view/partials/access.html',
            controller: 'AccessCtrl'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interceptor, all http class will go thrown the interceptor. Once the "resolve" piece is executed and return 401 you can redirect to the login screen or 403 to the forbidden view.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to change a state while a previous state change is still in course.
The ui-router has events for when a state change starts and ends.

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

});
```

So your redirect should be in there. Anyway I recommend you move that user check to a higher level in your app, like .run(), with some exception for the login states. That way you won't have to check in every controller individually.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've most updated version of angularjs & angular-ui. If you're using older version then check compatibility of angular-ui version with your angular version. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3246
If that doesn't work, add following line inside app.config

```
$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false)
```

don't forget add dependency `$qProvider` in config function.